# Changing Local Security Policy Programmatically

Tags: c#, local-security-policy

I want to change Local Security Policy "Interactive logon: do not require ctlr+alt+del" in C#. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

i found the answer i have to change in registry
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
"DisableCAD"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system]
"DisableCAD"=dword:00000001